# How should I emit a single value when observable completes?

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I want to **emit** one value when the original observable completes let's say like below, using the imaginary operator `mapComplete`:

```js
let arr = ['a','b', 'c'];

from(arr)
.pipe(mapComplete(()=>'myValue'))
.pipe(map((v)=>`further processed: ${v}`))
.subscribe(console.log)
//further processed: myValue
```

I tried the following which work but don't seem suitable:

**1.**

```js
from(arr)
.pipe(toArray())
.pipe(map(()=>'myValue'))
.pipe(map((v)=>`further processed: ${v}`))
.subscribe(console.log);
//further processed: myValue
```

**Issue:** If the original observable is a huge stream, i don't want to buffer it to an array, just to emit one value.

**2.**

```js
from(arr)
.pipe(last())
.pipe(map(()=>'myValue'))
.pipe(map((v)=>`further processed: ${v}`))
.subscribe(console.log);
//further processed: myValue
```

**issue:** If the stream completes without emitting anything I get an error: `[Error [EmptyError]: no elements in sequence]`

What would be a correct (in rxjs terms) way to do the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`ignoreElements`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/ignoreElements) to not emit anything and [`endWith`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/endWith) to emit a value on complete.

```ts
from(arr).pipe(
  ignoreElements(),
  endWith('myValue'),
  map(v => `further processed: ${v}`)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

If you want to execute a function in `map` you could use [`count()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/count) beforehand to emit one value on complete (the amount of values emitted).

```ts
from(arr).pipe(
  count(), // could also use "reduce(() => null, 0)" or "last(null, 0)" or "takeLast(1), defaultIfEmpty(0)" 
  map(() => getMyValue()),
  map(v => `further processed: ${v}`)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Nice answer. One note: for completeness, since the imaginary `mapComplete()` accepts a lambda it would be nice to provide a solution that calculates the value at the time of emission. I guess one extra map would solve it, but maybe there is some other solution also ..

Comment: @MarinosAn Yes you could use `map` after `endWith`. The only other option that's shorter that I could think of would be `count` before `map`. There are also a few alternatives to `count` but they are all longer as you can see in my edit.

Comment: I think the answer is now complete !

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve what you want by building your own custom operator.

The code could look like this

```
const emitWhenComplete = <T>(val: T) => <U>(source: Observable<U>) =>
  new Observable<T>((observer) => {
    return source.subscribe({
      error: (err) => observer.error(err),
      complete: () => {
        observer.next(val);
        observer.complete();
      },
    });
  });
```

Basically this operator would take in the source observable, ignore all values it emits, and emit only when the source completes.

You can look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xk9tbr?file=index.ts) for some tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `last()` operator with a default value. It would remove the `no elements in sequence` error when the stream is empty.

```js
from(arr).pipe(
  last(null, 'myValue'),  // `null` denotes no predicate
  map(_ => 'myValue'),    // map the last value from the stream
  map((v)=>`further processed: ${v}`)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: `last(null, 'myValue')` doesn't emit `myValue` as the last value if `from(arr)` emits something. So if  `from(arr)` emits anything you would still have to map its last value to `myValue` with `map(()=>'myValue')`.

Comment: @fridoo: Good point, I've edited the post. Thanks.